# Python: How to ignore decorators during unit (nose) tests?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-decorators, nose, numba

I want to ignore certain decorators on my code to have the associated functionality skipped, but only when running as a part of a unit test. Can this be done?

For example I have a function f, defined with a numba decorator like so:

```
@numba.jit
def f(a, b):
  return a + b
```

When I run a unit test that calls the above function I don't want the numba magic to happen, as it can slow things down and cause errors on some platforms. Is it possible to make a setting someplace that tells nose to run tests without any numba just-in-time (and/or all numba) decorators being applied?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, and I don't see how it would work; I think you'd have to write that yourself. For example, you could expose that function at a higher level in the module, using the `f = numba.jit(f)` form, then import the original, unwrapped version directly in your tests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For numba only, you can set an environment variable (eg. `export NUMBA_DISABLE_JIT=1`) to make the jit decorators no-ops.

http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/troubleshoot.html#disabling-jit-compilation

Comment: this flag will disable JIT at the process level, right?

Comment: Where would you specify ```export NUMBA_DISABLE_JIT=1``` ? I added a .numba_config.yaml file to my project repository, but that disables NUMBA globally, which is not what I want. I'd like to disable NUMBA only for the pytest sessions (or at least only for the coverage reports). Do you have an idea?

Comment: @merowinger. This is probably late but for anyone reading this later down the line, you can specify `os.environ["NUMBA_DISABLE_JIT"] = "1"` in conftest.py and it works.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to trick nose into using your own decorator that keeps the function unchanged.
Write a file `numba.py` that contains this function:

```
def jit(func):
    return func
```

and placed in your PYTHONPATH.
Either run your test from directory this file is located in or do this in
your test file as the first line:

```
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, 'path/to/dir/with/myfile')
```

Alternatively, you can set the environmental variable `PYTHONPATH` to the directory where your file is located.

Windows:

```
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;path/to/dir/with/myfile
```

Unix/Mac:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH$:path/to/dir/with/myfile
```

Comment: Worked for my test.

Comment: Yeah, it might not be very generalizable to libraries that have mixtures of decorators and other stuff. But for `numba` it is a good solution. Maybe for other libraries, it would be something like `module.decorator = lambda f:f`.

Answer (score 2):

You could patch the decorator with a new decorator which you could control:

```
import functools

def patch(parent, obj_name, switch_reg, switch_name):
    def gen_switcher():
        def wrapper(func):
            ori_wrapped = ori_decorator(func)
            @functools.wraps(func)
            def _(*args, **kwargs):
                if switch_reg.get(switch_name, False):
                    func_to_call = func
                else:
                    func_to_call = ori_wrapped
                print(func_to_call)
                return func_to_call(*args, **kwargs)
            return _
        return wrapper
    ori_decorator = getattr(parent, obj_name)
    setattr(parent, obj_name, gen_switcher())
```

with:

```
# have to patch the decorator before applying it
import numba
switchs = {}
patch(numba, 'jit', switchs, 'DISABLE_NUMBA_JIT')

@numba.jit
def f(a, b):
  return a + b

f(1, 2)
```

yields:

```
CPUDispatcher(<function f at 0x10a5f90d0>)
```

then with:

```
# this part could be rewrited as a context manager    
switchs['DISABLE_NUMBA_JIT'] = True
f(1, 2)
```

get:

```
<function f at 0x10a5f90d0>
```

Comment: This is more wizardry than I care to get into since there look to be simpler solutions, but "bravo!" nevertheless. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JamesAdams I haven't anticipated that your problem could be solved by simply google and read doc.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `coverage`, you can modify your CI `.yml` file by adding `NUMBA_DISABLE_JIT=1` right before your `coverage` command:

```sh
NUMBA_DISABLE_JIT=1 coverage run -p "test_*.py"
```

Answer (score 1):

I would separate the function into a non-decorated part that you unit test -- and then make your real function have the decorator and simply call the helper function:

```
@numba.jit
def f(a, b):
  return f_undecorated(a, b)

def f_undecorated(a, b):
  return a + b
```

Write the unit tests only for `f_undecorated`.

Comment: This is an interesting/clever approach, nice because it keeps you from needing to monkey with anything in the environment, it's all in code. However there's more code/complexity (nominal, really), so there's that. Not sure how it compares versus the answer above which is working for me (please advise). In any event thanks for your help, I appreciate your effort.